# Random segfaults when using what seems to be a typical implode statement

Tags: php, phalcon

Here's my function:

```
static function implode_conditions($query) {
    $conditions = $query['conditions'];
    if ($conditions) {
        $imploded_conditions = implode(" AND ", $conditions);
        $query['conditions'] = $imploded_conditions;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

`$query` is supposed to be something like:

```
$query = [
    'conditions' => ["client_id = :client_id:", "user_id = :user_id:"]
    'bind' => [
        'client_id' => 4,
        'user_id' => 8
    ]
```

The function is supposed to implode the 'conditions' part of the query, and stick " AND " between them.

Randomly, I'll get errors like:

`[Mon Sep 21 12:51:02.254969 2020] [core:notice] [pid 4895] AH00051: child pid 11991 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`

Or

`[Mon Sep 21 12:51:37.966151 2020] [php7:error] [pid 13562] [client 192.168.1.119:60682] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43654576528 bytes) in /mnt/my-project/app/library/QueryHelper.php on line 11, referer: http://192.168.1.100/cardcapture/`

And sometimes the error just disappears completely, but resurfaces.

When I comment out the implode, I never get the error, so I believe I have narrowed it down to the implode statement being the issue.

Comment: is app/library/QueryHelper.php that method? you could refactor that method into just a single line https://3v4l.org/XcUtY if your code is like that throughout no wounder it has memory issues. also, $query['conditions'] is entering into the method as an array and leaving as a string, which is not ideal

Comment: btw 43654576528 bytes is 43.65GB

Comment: They are semantically the same. Writing it as a one-liner using ternary syntax should make no difference.

Comment: no in your code your superfluously assigning multiple variables

Comment: That has nothing to do with segfaults. When you are explicit with the naming of your variables, your code becomes easier to understand. They are not "superfluous", they make the code easier to understand.

Comment: Did you try using \implode() ? Maybe implode is overridden somewhere?